# SQL Server Agent TSQL Job Error: Exporting query results into CSV and emailing CSV

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-agent

The following TSQL code fails with this error: *"Executed as user: . Failed to initialize sqlcmd library with error number -2147467259. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 22050).  The step failed."*

I'm unsure why, any help would be greatly appreciated! I tested this same query before without the delimiting stuff I had to add on. (The XML thing and the wrapping SELECT command from this article https://marc.durdin.net/2015/07/concatenating-strings-in-sql-server-or-undefined-behaviour-by-design/)

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@profile_name = 'IMGEMAIL',
@recipients = '~~~email~~~',
@subject = 'Sunday',
@query = N'
SET nocount ON;
DECLARE @data VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @delim VARCHAR(10) = '', ''

SELECT @data = (
SELECT
c.firstName AS FirstName + @delim
,c.lastName AS LastName + @delim
,c.userID AS CandidateID + @delim
,c.city AS CandidateCity + @delim
,c.state AS CandidateProvince + @delim
,u.primaryDepartment AS IMGDepartmentID + @delim
,d.name AS IMGDepartment + @delim
,js.dateadded AS JobSubDateAdded + @delim
,js.status AS JobSubStatus + @delim
,wh.companyName AS WorkHistoryCompanyName + @delim
,wh.startDATE AS WorkHistoryStartDate + @delim
,wh.endDATE as WorkhistoryEndDate + @delim
,wh.title AS WorkHistoryTitle
FROM 
[IanMartin_Datamart].[dbo].[JobSubmission] AS js
INNER JOIN
[IanMartin_Datamart].[dbo].[CandidateWorkHistory] AS wh ON    js.candidateID = wh.candidateID
INNER JOIN
[IanMartin_Datamart].[dbo].[Candidate] AS c ON c.userID = wh.candidateID
INNER JOIN
[IanMartin_Datamart].[dbo].[CorporateUser] AS u ON u.userID = js.sendingUserID
INNER JOIN
[IanMartin_Datamart].[dbo].[CorporationDepartment] AS d ON d.departmentID = u.primaryDepartment
WHERE
js.dateadded >= DATEADD(day,-7, GETDATE())
AND
js.status = ''Client Submission''
AND
u.primaryDepartment IN (28822, 28823, 28824)
AND
wh.startDATE >= ''2012-01-01''
ORDER BY 
js.candidateID
FOR XML PATH(''''), TYPE
).value(''.'',''varchar(max)'');
PRINT @Summary;',
@attach_query_result_as_file = 1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'bhLeads.csv',
@query_result_separator = ',',
@query_result_no_padding = 1
```

Comment: Are you on SQL 2014? If so make sure you're on the latest service pack.

Comment: The account that is running the job has the correct privs?

Comment: @Chuck Yea I'm pretty sure! I ran this same thing without the delims and the XML trick, and it emailed me fine.

Comment: @OlaEkdahl do I just run windows updates for that? How do I update to the latest service pack for SQL?

Comment: @ykadaru https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2958069/how-to-obtain-the-latest-service-pack-for-sql-server-2014